# HTML5 issue when playing MP4 (H.264) files on a Java EE application

Tags: html, jakarta-ee, video, jboss, mp4

We are trying to play videos and audios in our Java EE application, and we decided to use the **HTML5** `<video>` and `<audio>` tags rather than a Flash player.

We first tried it **outside** the java application, by creating simple HTML files, and we saw that some video/audio formats are not natively taken care of. 
In order to enable a maximum compatibility (we need the videos to work on **Chrome**, **Firefox** and **Safari**), we decided to upload the videos in the 3 following formats (video) : MP4, OGG and WebM.

*Now comes the problem :*

We tried to do the same **inside** the Java EE application (deployed on JBoss 7.1.1). 
Users first upload the video files from an uploading page, and then the application can display the video.

The problem is that now we get some issues which we didn't have previously (oustide Java app). The most problematic one being **MP4 not playing in Safari** when it was working perfectly fine when outside the application.

We thought the problem was coming from the upload of the videos, but they are working just fine with other browsers so **it doesn't seem to be linked to the upload**. We have similar problems with Chrome.

Our clue now is that the problem comes from **something wrong with our JBoss configuration**, but no idea where it comes from.

Another issue we have : even with the browser that can display the videos correctly, there is still an issue with the possibility to rewind or go forward with the cursor, while once again it is working just fine outside the application.

Comment: Firstly, you're not telling us how your Java EE web application is downloading the video. Secondly, have you used a Web debugger like Firebug to see what data are returned to your client and how your browser interprets your video data? Are you passing the correct `Content-Type`, `Content-Length` and data chunks (if streaming), etc.? What request headers does each web browser sends to retrieve the video and how is your application uses the request (including the header parameters), etc.? All these info varies in each browser. Also, do you know browser feature of the `<video />` and `<audio />`?

Comment: did you find the answer?